# Scrolling for android browser with foundation framework

Tags: android, web, scroll, zurb-foundation

I have been build a *mobile targeted site*, but want it to work on *desktop* also. For some reason the page will not scroll. I can zoom in the page, then scroll but obviously need this to work. Have no idea what is wrong and can't see anything wrong with my code:

example: http://damnationalley.vincentstephens.co.uk/

I am new to android development, any and all comments greatly welcomed

Answer (score 0):

Web site and wap site different technologi
If you want use WebView in html,css ve jquery codes you test http://jquerymobile.com/ web site and create your own wap code and than copy under assets directory and webview load url **file:///android_asset/**

Comment: Great, will look into that. Unfortunately I am building with foundation responsive frame work.  Actually I have found the answer but havent had a chance to post it yet.  Needed to wrap the head and footer in .row and add mobile two up class.  Thanks for the pointer to jquery mobile.  I am spending more time with jquery these days so look like a good option for the future.